# WinForms - Does the Form.DoubleBuffered property influence controls placed on that form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, doublebuffered

`Form` has the DoubleBuffered property (bool, inherited from Control).

If this is set to true, are all controls placed on the form drawn to screen in a double buffered fashion by virtue of being on the Form? Or do you need to worry about their own DoubleBuffered properties?

Comment: See my edit for a possible hack to get around this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I remember, no, double buffering does NOT carry over to child controls. You need to set it for each one individually. I'll google it and see if I can find a source to prove / disprove this...

EDIT: Found this: http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/topic17173.aspx

Just thought of a quick hack to get around this. Basically, use reflection to get the "DoubleBuffered" property, and then set it:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void EnableDoubleBuferring(this Control control)
    {
        var property = typeof(Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        property.SetValue(control, true, null);
    }
}
```

Then, in  your form code, do something like this:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            control.EnableDoubleBuferring();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This sounds like a bit of a PITA.

Comment: Thanks again. Looks a handy way in general to quickly mess with non-public things.

Comment: Still useful in 2018 :P