# Flickering on background colour change

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, flicker

I have a large panel with many child panels inside of it. Inside of those child panels are two text fields with a transparent background. It is essentially ListBox built from scratch.

What I am trying to do is loop through each of those child panels and change their background colour to a selected colour when a user clicks on one.

However, when I click on a new child panel, there is a very noticable flicker between the old background colour and the new background colour.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ROHYu.png]

*Note: The light blue colour is a highlighting colour when the user hovers over a panel.*

I have tried setting DoubleBuffered to true for the main panel and the form itself without much luck. I've also tried setting ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, ControlStyles.UserPaint and ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer to true as well.

```
public class List : Panel
{
    private Panel[] items;
    private Label[] header; // Children of items
    private Label[] footer; // Children of items

    public List()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);

        AutoScroll = true;
        BackColor = Color.White;
        //DoubleBuffered = true;
        HorizontalScroll.Visible = false;
        HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;
        VerticalScroll.Visible = true;
        VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
    }

    public void renderItemsSelected(Color color)
    {
        for (int q = 0; q < itemsSelected.Count; q++)
        {
            int i = getPos();

            items[i].BackColor = color;
        }
    }
}
```

So I was wondering if anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WinForms - Does the Form.DoubleBuffered property influence controls placed on that form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911376/winforms-does-the-form-doublebuffered-property-influence-controls-placed-on-th)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer here:

[WinForms - Does the Form.DoubleBuffered property influence controls placed on that form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911376/winforms-does-the-form-doublebuffered-property-influence-controls-placed-on-th/911441#911441)

Basically, setting DoubleBuffered on a parent control doesn't trickle down to child controls. Try the hack that I proposed in that answer, see if that works for you.

Comment: Enabling double buffering for each item in the 'items' array worked. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. I used the following to solve.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal static class NativeWinAPI
{
    internal static readonly int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    internal static readonly int WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000;

    [DllImport("user32")]
    internal static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    internal static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
}
```

Then use in the main Form like this:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    int style = NativeWinAPI.GetWindowLong(this.Handle, NativeWinAPI.GWL_EXSTYLE);
    style |= NativeWinAPI.WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
    NativeWinAPI.SetWindowLong(this.Handle, NativeWinAPI.GWL_EXSTYLE, style);
}
```

[Reference: CodeProject 'Solution 1'](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/473175/FlickeringplusinplusaplusWindowsplusFormplusapplic)